# Can i customize carrier-wave uploader to save its dimensions

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave

I dont want to add another column in the model to save the dimensions of the file being uploaded. 
Is there any way to add another key to carrier-wave uploaded file itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like [this guide from the docs](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to:-Get-image-dimensions) shows how to assign, save, and get image dimensions without adding another column to the model's table.

Comment: In case we use 'Minimagick', we need to have two columns 'width' and 'height'. What if I don't want any other column in my model?